# How to work with scaffolding and different repositories

Tags: repository, scaffolding

I am planning some projects. I don't care about the technology, the language and the framework. The doubt is conceptual, how to work with the base structure.

I have a repository in Bitbucket with a base scaffolding (repository: scaffolding).

- I start the project A from that scaffolding. How? a fork? a clone of that repository?
- I start project B, from that scaffoldinb. How, a fork, a clone of that repository?

And all of a sudden, I update things in the scaffolding, and I need project A and B to download those base changes.

How should this be set up so that if the scaffolding updates the rest of the projects easily?

Comment: I think I have succeeded.
I used this reference: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/how-to-auto-sync-forked-repositories-in-bitbucket-cloud-1223820803.html

Is this correct?